# Incorrect data returned from HTTP.get in Meteor server

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor app that allows users to upload images.
The result of the image upload is stored in a CollectionFS.
The system is then used to accept or reject images and push the image to a third party SQL database.  To do this I use HTTP.get to pull the image from the Meteor app, convert it from binary to hex and use a stored proc to push it into the SQL database.

My issue is with the HTTP.get response and converting it to hex.

```
var imageData = Images.find({_id: imageId}).fetch();
var studentId = imageData[0].metadata.ownerStudentID;
result = HTTP.get(Meteor.absoluteUrl()+imageData[0].url());
imageString = new Buffer(result.content,'binary').toString('hex');
```

The result of 'imageString' is indeed a hex string, but it does not match the image as tested with a hex editor.  Its actually significantly different.
[hex editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssJLM.png)

Prior to using CollectionFS I was using a standard Mongo.Collection and storing the base64 version of the image, then converting this to hex using the same idea above, and this worked fine.  Its only since Ive had to switch to CollectionFS and retrieve the image via HTTP.get that this issue has occurred.

Any ideas?